# Virtual Switch equivalents with VMWare Workstation

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I am following a lab manual for setting up some Windows Server 2016 servers. In the introduction it the book talks about using Hyper-V with both an `Internal Virtual Switch` and a `Private Virtual Switch`. The problem is I only have access to VMWare Workstation. How do I go about setting this up correctly with VMWare Workstation? **See my questions at the bottom of this section to see if I am thinking about this correctly.**

The textbook I am using is called [MCSA Guide to Identity with Windows Server 2016](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1337400890) by *Greg Tomsho*. The pertinent section on page xviii is as follows:

> Some activities require your VMs to access the Internet. An easy way
>   to accommodate this is to install the Remote Access role on your
>   Hyper-V host (if you’re using Hyper-V and Windows Server 2016 for your
>   host computer) and configure NAT so your Hyper-V host can route
>   packets to the physical network and the Internet. After installing the
>   Remote Access role with the Routing role service, configure NAT and
>   select the interface connected to the physical network as the public
>   interface and the interface connected to the Hyper-V internal switch
>   as the private interface. The interface connected to the Hyper-V
>   internal switch should be configured with address 192.168.0.250/24.

A diagram also shows the setup:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. The above quoted text talks about installing the Remote Access Role on the Host machine. Is this needed? What is its purpose? We are using Windows 10 on the host machine.
2. Is the `Private Virtual Switch` equivalent to Host-Only Networking (VMnet1) in VMWare Workstation?
3. Is the `Internal Virtual Switch` equivalent to `NAT` networking (VMnet8) in VMWare Workstation?

Comment: Internal Virtual Switch is equivalent to Host only networking.  The private virtual switch is a VM only switch, no host or external network access. RRAS plus the Internal virtual switch would be about the same as NAT, except that with VMware NAT the hosts don't communicate with each other.  Ideally, on VMware Workstation you'd set up a host-only network, create a linux router VM with 2 vNICS, and add one vNIC to this host-only network and another vNIC to the NAT or bridged network to get the equivalent of what's highlighted in yellow.